# How can I see inside cvHaarDetectObjects() in openCV?

Tags: opencv, time, viola-jones

I am trying to optimize the Viola-Jones code written in pure C code since it takes longer to detect faces than the code using the openCV function.

I want to see how cvHaarDetectObjects function actually work but I can't find how.

Can anybody help me out here please?

Comment: Did you try and find it in the OpenCV sources ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can browse code online - https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/haar.cpp

Comment: Just be careful that the online version is the same version of OpenCV you have!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/?source=navbar) to download the source code so you can see how it was written. Make sure it is the same version as the one you are running
2. Run the .exe file you just downloaded and specify a place to unpack the OpenCV library. It unpacks more than just the library itself; it includes plenty of helpful samples and documentation among other things
3. Go to wherever you unpacked it and go to *\modules\objdetect\src\haar.cpp* and open it in whatever editor you want
4. Press ctrl+F or whatever you need to do to search for text and look for **cvHaarDetectObjects**
5. Absorb knowledge